# Vue.js filter table

Tags: vue.js, filter

I'm new in vue.js, I would like to filter the following table by "Director ID".

When I load the page I would like to show only rows where director ID is 18. I need the table to filter right away without any user input. I would like to "hardcode" the ID 18 in to the function.

Thank you for your help!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><h1 class="mt-3">List of all Movies</h1></div>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Movie ID</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Release Year</th>
          <th>Director ID</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id">
          <td>{{ movie.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.releaseYear }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.director.id }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      movies: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "They All Lie",
          releaseYear: 1989,
          director: {
            id: 18,
            firstName: "Darci",
            lastName: "Overill",
            nationality: "China",
            birthdate: "07/13/1973",
          },
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Star Wars",
          releaseYear: 1997,
          director: {
            id: 18,
            firstName: "Darci",
            lastName: "Overill",
            nationality: "China",
            birthdate: "07/13/1973",
          },
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "Mamma mia",
          releaseYear: 2005,
          director: {
            id: 19,
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Smith",
            nationality: "USA",
            birthdate: "07/13/1980",
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change the `tr` to:

```
 <tr v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie.id" v-if="movie.director.id === 18">
```

**UPDATE**
We wrote at the same time with @tuhin47.

I prefer his way to be honest with only a minor change in computed.
I changed the `el` to `movie` just to be more clear :)

```
computed: {
    filteredMovies() {
      return this.movies.filter((movie) => movie.director.id === 18);
    },
  },
```

Comment: thank you for your help! it works flawlessly. One more question:

Now I'm trying to I to use this.$route.params.id instead of the actual number in the computed function. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks again!

Comment: Do you mean that you have a router page like /movies/:movieId and you want access in :movieId in the computed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property for filtering data and `v-for` the filtered data.
Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-jennings-5txv1?file=/src/App.vue)

```
<tbody>
        <tr v-for="movie in filteredMovies" :key="movie.id">
          <td>{{ movie.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.releaseYear }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.director.id }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Here is the computed property:

```
computed: {
    filteredMovies() {
      return this.movies.filter((el) => el.director.id === 18);
    },
  },
```

Comment: thank you for your help! it works flawlessly. One more question: Now I'm trying to I to use this.$route.params.id instead of the actual number in the computed function. How can I achieve this? Many thanks again!